# how to initialize chromium embedded framework 3 in another thread?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

A multi-process mode Delphi chromium embedded framework 3 program usually, as shown in the supplied [guiclient.dpr](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/demos/guiclient/guiclient.dpr) example, initialize the cef3 library in the .dpr file like this:

```
CefSingleProcess := False;
if not CefLoadLibDefault then
  Exit;
```

But how can I instead initialize cef3 (multi-process mode) in **another thread** (to speed up the program startup)?

I have done some tests by putting the above mentioned initialization code into another thread, but it causes multiple instances of the programs to run, or hang the program...

Comment: This is likely to be impossible. GUI / main thread affinity as usual.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No you can use DCEF3 in threads. Its just a bit tedious.

Comment: @user How is it done?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Using `OTL` its a breeze.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Infact `TEmbeddedWB` is even easier to thread. Because `DCEF3` has this absolutely stupid multi process architecture.

Comment: @user Do you have any detail?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I use your and `gabr` improved thread safe `DSiAllocateHWnd/DSiDeallocateHWnd` works wonders. Plus other techniques.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Although `CreateWindow` is better. by far